# Сохранение checked елеметов

Tags: php, javascript, json, checkbox

Как мне сохранить состояние элементов  на странице? Чтобы на емейл пришла ссылка с элементами которые выбрал пользователь. И при переходе на эту ссылку были  элементы которые выбрал пользователь?
вот пример https://estimatemyapp.com

Comment: сохнаить например атрибут value  у checkbox, передать его на сервер и с сервера послать value на страницу на которую переходит пользователь, найти сhackbox с таким value и поставить chacked = true;
сработает?

Comment: не,там на емейл приходит ссылка и если перейти то там будет такая же страница только с выбраными елементами

Answer (score 0):

Можете добавить GET параметрами значение чекбоксов. 
Например: http://estimatemyapp.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов: в процессе обработки данных на сервере перед отправкой на e-mail сохранять значения checkbox'ов в базе одной записью, с присвоением этой  записи какого либо ID, на указанный адрес электронной почты отправляется url с этим ID - типа `https://estimatemyapp.com/?checkid=aaabbbcccccc`, ну или как на указанном вами сайте. При переходе по ссылке определяется запись, соответствующая данному ID, и значения checkbox'ов расставляются в соответствии с выбором пользователя.
Детали реализации - на ваше усмотрение.